# Comparing data files

Tags: time-series

We have several weather files for a year's data sampled hourly. In each we have several variables (up to ten), temperature, wind speed, solar intensity etc.

I would like to try and develop a system that could determine if these files are statistically different. If I was using a single variable, I could use a KS-test, but with a collection of variables how should I approach this problem?

Comment: Could you please be more specific about the "files" and what you mean by "whether files are different". E.g., in each file do you have a univariate time series and you'd like to know whether the trend of each of these time series is different or something similar? Or how do you define different based on a file? It would be best if you included an example.

Comment: Each file consists of about 10 univariate time series. What I would like to see is a p-value to see if I can reject the null hypothesis that the files are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Kolmogorov-Smirnov for each variable - this will tell you the p-value for each one being different.

Now you have 10 binary values (telling you whether the original variable failed the KS), and you need to test the hypothesis that the "yes" values occurred at random with probability at most `p`.

Comment: Interesting, done some research and found this to be a really complicated problem, and quickly becomes intractable. I think your solution is the best I've seen for practically handling this.